# Should I use 'are' or 'were' in the sentence?

Tags: grammar

The original sentence is:

> It is said that the President's New Deal created thousands of jobs.

I changed this sentence to:

> Thousands of jobs **are/were** said to be created by the President's New Deal.

Should I use ***are*** or ***were***?

Comment: In the original sentence, the verb to be is in PRESENT tense. It is said now, in the PRESENT. It does not provide information about what was said in the past.

Comment: @RubioRic  So should I use ‘are’?

Comment: Yes, I think so.

Comment: I agree, "are", but I think the second sentence needs "are said to have been created" to keep that clause in the past.